# How to restore the previous value of index template in elastic search which got overrided by PUT request?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

How to restore the previous value of index template in elastic search which got overrided by PUT request ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you have done a [snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html) prior to overriding the index template.

Older versions of templates, documents, etc are not kept anywhere, you need to back them up yourself if you need them.